# Define dot functions like jQuery's ".map()", ".each()", etc

Tags: javascript, jquery, constructor, javascript-objects, prototype

I have 2 functions and one constructor defined like this :

```
let mx = function(arr) {
    return new mx.fn.init(arr) 
}

mx.fn = mx.prototype = {
    constructor: mx,
}

init = mx.fn.init = function(arr) {
    //do things and return an object containing data about arr
}
```

So this code works well and calling `mx(array)` returns the wanted object.
Now, how can I define functions **to manipulate this object**? I would like to define functions like, for example, `mx(array).addRow(row)` to change data in the object returned by `mx(array)` but can't manage to do it.
I tried to define it in `mx.fn` like this :
`addRow: function(arr) { //do smth }` but it doesn't work.
I also tried to do `mx.prototype.addRow = function(row) { //do smth }`.
Do you know if this is possible? It looks like jQuery's `$('#id').css('color': 'red')` a lot but I'm not sure if this works the same way.
I'm new to a lot of these concepts so I'm a bit lost in all those prototypes...

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `prototype` of the `init` function.

```
let mx = function(arr) {
    return new mx.fn.init(arr) 
}
let init = function(arr) {
    //do things and return an object containing data about arr
}
mx.fn = init.prototype = {
    addRow(row){
        // do something
    },
    init: init
}
```